# print to Flash in C#

Tags: c#, flash, printing

I need an easy way to show different document-types (.doc, .xls, .jpg...) in webpages.
Ideally a user prints or saves that document and that document is automatically converted to Adobe-Flash.

I know there are existing solutions to this. However, I would like to implement them in my own application, written in C#.

Can anyone point me in a direction how to write a "Printer" in C#, where printable documents can be printed to, and that outputs a SWF-File?

Thanks,
Reinhard

Comment: I feel really confused about what you want, as you're talking about web pages, and then about printing, but when I work in Web Pages I rely on the Browser's print, which is a little off limits for the web developer. Lastly, I completely don't understand (or agree) why it's ideal to print to Flash. Could you clarifying?

Comment: It might be easier to print to PDF and have PDFs somehow converted on the server side.

Comment: @Richard:
With "Print OR Save" I meant printing to a PDF-File or saving that file in its native applications format, and then convert that file to Flash which is then shown inside a webpage.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is quite what you're looking for, but have you seen iText for .NET?

http://www.ujihara.jp/iTextdotNET/en/

Comment: From what I saw at a quick look, this library can be usefull for creating PDF from C#.
However, I am looking for a way to convert EXISTING PFDs, DOCs..etc.. to Adobe-FLASH

Comment: Then you may want to look at SWFTOOLS (http://www.swftools.org/about.html); they advertise a program to convert PDF to SWF.

It does not look like it is a library, so you will have to "shell out" from C#/.NET to execute it, but it looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

Try Print2Flash ([www.print2flash.com](http://www.print2flash.com)). It seems to be ideally suited to this purpose. It even has a SDK which has a C# sample which demonstrates how it is possible to convert any printable document to Flash with C#.

Answer (score 0):

An idea would be convert all files to 2 formats: ideally PDF for printing and jpeg for viewing in flash. There are ways to convert most documents to PDF, printing from PDF will be optimal and enable you to get from .doc to jpeg.

GhostScript is a PDF interpretter that can convert PDF to jpeg. Its open source.

There are also fully managed .Net commercial components that can convert PDF to Jpg. Search for "Tall Components PDF"

Comment: That is one way I could take... print to a PDF-File.
But then... How do I convert a PDF to FLASH or SILVERLIGHT - I want to show the contents in a webpage

Comment: You need to convert each page to a format that flash or silverlight can display, most probably jpg and load in the pages dynamically. You will need to build the interface to display the images, slideshow, single page view or replicate an acrobat style interface etc.